# TimeSpan End Not Working in GoogleEarth

Tags: kml, google-earth, timespan

I have a series of placemarks I want to display in a series. I have the following xml for each:

```
<Placemark>
 <name>10m Radius Circle</name>
  <TimeSpan>
   <begin>2015-04-14T14:00:00-07:00</begin>
   <end>2015-04-14T15:00:00-07:00</end>
  </TimeSpan>
 <styleUrl>#stylemap_id0</styleUrl>
 <LineString>
  <coordinates>
   [coordinate data here]
  </coordinates>
 </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

Each of the 6 placemarks should display for an hour, then switch to the next. They do appear, but don't disappear.

I've tried to change the time interval to 1 day, but that doesn't work either.

I was under the impression that the  tag meant the placemark no longer showed, but that isn't working.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you need to drag the "crescent-shaped control" to the slider.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you first load KML in Google Earth with multiple times the time span in the time slider opens to the full extent to show Placemarks for all times unless explicitly overridden with a specific time range.

If you change the time slider to show only a one hour interval then you should see one of your lines assuming each line is set for a different hour.

You can define the KML to only show a specific time range upon loading by setting a [LookAt](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#lookat) with the same time range as first placemark on the root document. To do this easily just double click on the first placemark then right-click on the Document in Places panel and select 'Snapshot View'. This will add a LookAt to the Document and force showing only the time range of the first placemark. Save the updated KML to see the changes.

Comment: I do see the lines appear, but they don't disappear. In other words, they appear and hang around, long after the TimeSpan has expired.

Comment: To make debugging easier suggest changing times to UTC format; e.g. 2015-04-14T21:00:00Z then change time slider options to show time in UTC. Next change the time slider window show a small time interval - what do you see.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It turns out to have been a playback issue. (There's a strange crescent-shaped control on the OS X version, which caused the problem.)